# Aloha editor - connecting a directory in the repository browser

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

I am experimenting with the Aloha inline HTML5 editor (www.aloha-editor.com).

I am creating a CMS system that will allow the administrator to upload files for download.

These will go into an upload directory (public_html/upload).

When a user wants to put in a link they can click the repository browser and be presented with a list of files in this upload folder.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I don't understand the documentation at all, and even copying the javascript source from their examples isn't helping at all.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you making yet another CMS?

Comment: I work with clients in the pharmaceutical industry who have a specific set of requirements and all require certain functionality not present in standard CMS systems. I'm not trying to make another joomla or drupal or anything, this is a specific CMS for my own development projects, one which I can understand, one which I can extend or modify easily because I made it and one which comes with all the functionality I need, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Regulated software, that's cool, just wanted to make sure you weren't making more work than you needed... it happens all too often in software.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: and how will you deal with licensing?

Comment: As per http://aloha-editor.org/license.php we would have probably released it as an open source project. It was nothing special, just a CMS with a few different features. However there were problems with it, including its lack of support of all browsers (ie6 and above is a necessity). So we used something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement an Aloha repository.
you should get enough information on this discussion : http://getsatisfaction.com/aloha_editor/topics/how_to_add_a_directory_to_the_repository_window

Please feel free to ask more, i've done the stuff, so i could help.

Best regards

Comment: thanks for this. :) I found some examples and I've managed to get something together. Its very very confusing! But I got there in the end! :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson, could you share these samples? (if you remember them at all :) )

Comment: Sorry... very long time ago, and we used a different solution in the end, so I don't even have the original code. Have a search around the internet. That's presumably how I found it.

Comment: I have been unsuccesful in my attempts to get a basic repository running. As I mentioned in the Get Satisfaction discussion, the documentation on the subject lacks to mention how to actually wire up a repository to an editor. There is some Aloha Dev’s dropping in on the subject and suggesting work-arounds, but without an actual code sample it is hard to apply that advice to practice.

Comment: So my question is: can you provide a code sample for the integration of a basic repository (for example, the basic link repository example from Aloha itself) into the Aloha Editor? Cheers,